# ProgressDialog not show in activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I'm writing an Android application. In one of my activities, I call the method `updateAPI()` that updates the data from the database to a server.

Here is the code of my method:

```
    private void updateAPI(){
    boolean stop = false;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Updating...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
    while(!stop){
        List<ApplicationKeyId> list = MyApplication.getApplicationId_updated(false);
        if (list != null) {
                ApplicationInformation appInfo = MyApplication.getApplicationInformation(app.getPackageName());
                try {
                    applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(app.getPackageName(), 0);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String appName = (pm.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) == null) ? app.getApplicationName() : (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo);

                List<UsedApplication> listUsa = appInfo.getApplicationToUsedApp();
                for (UsedApplication usa : listUsa) {
                    if (DateUnit.compare2Days(usa.getDate(), app.getDate())) {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.setTime(new Date(usa.getDate().getTime()));
                        String dateApp = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + DateUnit.MonthtoString(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        Map<String, String> datamap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        String results = dateApp + "_" + usa.getTime();
                        datamap.put("dataKey", appName);
                        datamap.put("dataValue", results);
                        datamap.put("company", "Privowny");
                        datamap.put("encrypt", String.valueOf(false));
                        if (app.getKeyId() == null) CallAPI.sendPost(datamap);
                        else CallAPI.sendPut(datamap, app.getKeyId());
                    }
                }
            }
            stop = true;
        }
    }
    if(stop) progressDialog.dismiss();

}
```

In case where there are many data lines which need to be updated I want to show a `progressDialog` to tell user to wait.

I tried to use a `progressDialog` in the method but it didn't show up.

Here, I couldn't use `AsynTask` class because in my method the class `CallAPI.sendPut` (`CallAPI.sendPost`) has already used `Asyntask`. I think if I use it here, there will be a thread collision.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that your method is being executed and the variable stop is false? , this line  if(stop) progressDialog.dismiss(); causes the progressdialog will dissapear!

Comment: Hi Elenasys, I checked my code by adding a log and my method is called. At the begin of the method, I set stop= false, after posting or putting data to server, it is set true so that progressDialog could be dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your work ( everything in the while ) on a different thread. Now everything is on the main-thread which explains what you see

Comment: Hi Ligi, could we can call asynsTask in a thread? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please use callbacks when asynktask wil be finished (CallAPI.sendPut).